# WSO2 - How to use Endpoint template in Registry resource project?

Tags: templates, wso2, registry, endpoint

```
<call>
  <endpoint key="gov:/custom/endpoint.xml"/>
</call>
```

Using endpoint is straight forward.

But, what is the proper way to use it for template endpoint?

I tried and editor refuse it.

```
<call>
  <endpoint key="gov:/custom/endpoint-template.xml" template="mytemplate" name"myname"/>
</call>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the registry path to the `template` parameter not the `key` parameter. Can you try the following config?

```xml
<call>
  <endpoint template="gov:/custom/endpoint-template.xml" name"myname"/>
</call>
```